# How to mock data for cassandra when using spark cassandra connector in spark streaming testing?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a code written entirely in scala which uses spark streaming to get json data from kafka topic and then dump it to cassandra and another kafka topic after some processing. Now I need to write an unit test for this code. I need help on how to write such a test and how we can mock data when I am using spark cassandra connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spark-cassandra-connector-embedded](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/10_embedded.md) that is developed together with connector itself. Just add the Maven or SBT dependency to your project, like, this for SBT:

```
"com.datastax.spark"  %% "spark-cassandra-connector-embedded" % {latest.version}
```